# AFNetWorking serialize response error

Tags: ios, iphone, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I make request with the code:

```
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializerWithReadingOptions:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments];
    [manager GET:requestURLString
      parameters:nil
         success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
             callCompletion(nil);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        callCompletion(error);
    }];
```

Had the error:

```
  Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (Invalid value around character 0.) UserInfo=0x7fa261cf2720 {NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}
```

My response will look like :

```
 callback_1437492189642({"project":"2330","session":1408257});
```

How can I serialize it?

Comment: What it basically says is that it is invalid JSON

Comment: Yes, I understand that response is not JSON, but How can I handle it?

Comment: oh, sorry. you have access to the operation.responseObject, try to print it, and enter the output to a linter, http://pro.jsonlint.com.
edit: I saw it's empty. are you sure your backend is fully working? print the operation.response.statusCode and see if the status is something else than `200`

Comment: @Simon, status code is 200